# MP4 in-browser video playback intermittently broken on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, video, mp4

This one is really puzzling and we suspect an iOS bug.

**Situation:**

We have a video content site, where we host videos as `mp4` and users can play them back. These videos are shown inline in HTML5 players in the browser. Often a user will have multiple videos displayed on the same page.

**Problem**

We started receiving reports from some users, all on iOS devices, that a small subset of those videos were showing up for them as unplayable, like below:

[image]

Now again, this wouldn't happen for all of the videos on their screen, just a few. When the videos are viewed on a non-iOS device, everything is fine; all videos are playable. For these users, it doesn't matter what browser they use on that device, the same problem happens.

**What we've looked into**

At first, we looked into common HTML5 video playback issues associated with Safari (and iOS). Things like making sure the server was responding to `Range` requests and including `playsinline` and so on. The requests and responses looked fine, which made sense because these videos are all transcoded to the same format and hosted on the same server (Digital Ocean Spaces).

Once we were able to reproduce this issue on iOS, we saw that it wasn't the video tag; even accessing the `mp4` directly (no HTML) in the browser (doesn't matter which one) would not work:

[image]

This would support the idea that it doesn't work on any browser. Here's a few puzzling details we found from our testing (we are testing using an online service that provides us access to iOS simulators):

- This only happens with some (a small subset of our) videos, most videos will *always* work
- For the videos that do not work, for every **simulator** restart, there is roughly a 50/50 chance whether it will work or not. If it works (or not), it will stay in that state until another restart
- Within the same simulator session, no number of **device* restarts will change the state from not working to working
- It appears to happen on iOS 12.4 and above, iPad and iPhone (tested using the simulator)

When you search the Apple forums, there are quite a few recent issues around video playback, more centered around the 13.4 update.

**Example**

We were able to re-create this with stock videos. Just for context, it took us about 16 videos before we got 1 failure.

[Working](https://vh-prod-seg.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/3600376534f55e6f148aba3a32f38949.mp4)

[Not working](https://vh-prod-seg.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/4067488dcd26b818035bd0674671ec71.mp4)

When we access the "not working" link in an iOS simulator (iPhone XS, iOS 12.4), it fails every time.

Anyway, we are running out of ideas as to how this can be resolved and perhaps simply looking for confirmation that this may be a known iOS issue. Did anyone experience this?

Comment: Please post a sample of a video that will not work.

Comment: Good point @szatmary, working on a sample that we can share publicly and will post that here when we have it.

Comment: Example added @szatmary

Answer (score 2):

The non working file is yuv422 colorspace (see `Chroma subsampling : 4:2:2` below). Most hardware (therefore mobile) decoders can only play yuv420. The file must be transcoded to a supported colorspace.

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High 4:2:2@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 16 s 984 ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 760 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 496 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.258
Stream size                              : 5.59 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 157 r2969 d4099dd
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=15 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Color range                              : Full
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

The simulators works sometimes, because they are simulating the decoder in software. And many software decoders do support 4:2:2

Comment: Thank you, but I don't believe that is the only factor. We have other non-working examples that are yuv420p (that unfortunately I cannot share). I could paste their specs, but it gets quite verbose. Are there other encodings that the iOS devices might struggle with?

Comment: Then you will need to post those files too. I can only check the things you post. But THIS file is not working because of the color space. "Are there other encodings that the iOS devices might struggle with?" Yes, hundreds.

Comment: Here is another one that is not working: https://pastebin.com/vFCCmKsk

Comment: Sometimes the ffprobe is not enough. I would need to see the files.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I could get them to you in confidence?

Comment: I provide free help for people here on stackoverflow in public in hopes it helps you as well as other people. I apologies, but I do not generally do free private consulting.

Comment: I understand and I appreciate your help. It's that the videos are not to be shared publicly. What tool(s) could we run on them that would give better information?

Comment: I you have additional questions. Please make a new post.

Comment: It's the same question; I'm just trying to be able to post more contextual information for it.

Comment: The correct place for contextual information is in the question body not the comments. Stack overflow comments should be used very sparingly. Stackoverflow is not a conversational or threaded forum like reddit. 1 question = 1 answer. You asked about a video, it was answered, you are now asking about a different video. That is a different question.